# Mirroring details inside a section view using the Revit API

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I have some detail lines inside a section view that I would like to mirror across the midpoint of the `CropBox` for the section.  I'm using the `ElementTransformUtils.MirrorElements` to try and accomplish this.  However, I have not yet been able to find the correct plane upon which to mirror the detail lines.  I've tried `Plane.CreateByNormalAndOrigin(section.ViewDirection, section.Origin)` and `detailLine.SketchPlane.GetPlane()` but none of those have mirrored the detail lines.

[image: Mirroring Detail Lines]

What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get my details to mirror across the midpoint of the `ViewSection.CropBox` but it was rather complicated.  I discovered that the `ViewSection.Origin` is a point in the project coordinate system.  The `ViewSection.CropBox`, on the other hand, does not give you its Min and Max in the project coordinate system but instead gives you the location of the CropBox relative to the `ViewSection.Origin`.  Using the `ViewSection.Origin` and `ViewSection.CropBox` you can calculate the Min and Max of the `ViewSection.CropBox` in the project coordinate system.  Finally, you need to use those Min and Max values to find the midpoint of the `ViewSection.CropBox` and then mirror across that point.

Here are some helper classes I use so that I can find the Min and Max using a single function

```
public enum PointComponent
{
  Invalid,
  X,
  Y,
  Z
}

public enum MinOrMax
{
  Invalid,
  Min,
  Max
}
```

Here's the function to find the X, Y, or Z component of the Min or Max of the CropBox:

```
private double GetSectionCropBoxOrigin(ViewSection section,
  PointComponent pointComponent, MinOrMax minOrMax)
{
  double cropBoxOrigin;

  double sectionOrigin, viewDirection, upDirection, rightDirection;

  switch (pointComponent)
  {
    case PointComponent.X:
      sectionOrigin = section.Origin.X;
      viewDirection = section.ViewDirection.X;
      upDirection = section.UpDirection.X;
      rightDirection = section.RightDirection.X;
      break;
    case PointComponent.Y:
      sectionOrigin = section.Origin.Y;
      viewDirection = section.ViewDirection.Y;
      upDirection = section.UpDirection.Y;
      rightDirection = section.RightDirection.Y;
      break;
    case PointComponent.Z:
      sectionOrigin = section.Origin.Z;
      viewDirection = section.ViewDirection.Z;
      upDirection = section.UpDirection.Z;
      rightDirection = section.RightDirection.Z;
      break;
    default:
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
  }

  double cropX, cropY;

  switch (minOrMax)
  {
    case MinOrMax.Min:
      cropX = section.CropBox.Min.X;
      cropY = section.CropBox.Min.Y;
      break;
    case MinOrMax.Max:
      cropX = section.CropBox.Max.X;
      cropY = section.CropBox.Max.Y;
      break;
    default:
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
  }

  if (Math.Abs(viewDirection) == 1)
    cropBoxOrigin = sectionOrigin;
  else if (Math.Abs(upDirection) == 1)
    cropBoxOrigin = sectionOrigin + (cropY * upDirection);
  else if (Math.Abs(rightDirection) == 1)
    cropBoxOrigin = sectionOrigin + (cropX * rightDirection);
  else
    throw new InvalidOperationException();

  return cropBoxOrigin;
}
```

Notice that for `PointComponent.Z` we do not use the midpoint between Min and Max values and instead use the origin.  This is because our detail work only exists in 2D even though we specify a `CropBox` depth and the detail work sits at the same depth as the `ViewSection.Origin`.

Here's the code I use to get the midpoint:

```
private XYZ Get3dMidpoint(XYZ start, XYZ end)
{
    double x = (start.X + end.X) / 2.0;
    double y = (start.Y + end.Y) / 2.0;
    double z = (start.Z + end.Z) / 2.0;

    return new XYZ(x, y, z);
}
```

And finally here's the code to bring it all together and get the mirror plane:

```
XYZ cropBoxMinInGlobalCoordinates = new XYZ(
    GetSectionCropBoxOrigin(section, PointComponent.X, MinOrMax.Min),
    GetSectionCropBoxOrigin(section, PointComponent.Y, MinOrMax.Min),
    GetSectionCropBoxOrigin(section, PointComponent.Z, MinOrMax.Min)
);
XYZ cropBoxMaxInGlobalCoordinates = new XYZ(
    GetSectionCropBoxOrigin(section, PointComponent.X, MinOrMax.Max),
    GetSectionCropBoxOrigin(section, PointComponent.Y, MinOrMax.Max),
    GetSectionCropBoxOrigin(section, PointComponent.Z, MinOrMax.Max)
);
XYZ cropBoxOriginInGlobalCoordinates = 
  Get3dMidpoint(cropBoxMinInGlobalCoordinates, cropBoxMaxInGlobalCoordinates);

Plane mirrorPlane = 
  Plane.CreateByNormalAndOrigin(section.RightDirection, cropBoxOriginInGlobalCoordinates);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the planes that you mention will not mirror as you expect.

You need a plane that is perpendicular to the detail line, I assume.

That would mirror a horizontal detail line such as you show from right to left or vice versa.

You can determine the mirror plane normal and origin from the detail line itself:

```
  XYZ p = detail line start point
  XYZ q = detail line end point
  XYZ normal = q - p
  Plane plane = Plane.CreateByNormalAndOrigin(p, normal)
```

More or less...